# Deleting one line within txt file in Python

Tags: python

I am having problems deleting a specific line/entry within a text file. With the code I have the top line in the file is deleted no matter what line number I select to delete.

```
def erase():
   contents = {}
   f = open('members.txt', 'a')
   f.close()
   f = open('members.txt', 'r')
   index = 0
   for line in f:
      index = index + 1
      contents[index] = line
      print ("{0:3d}) {1}".format(index,line))
   f.close()
   total = index
   entry = input("Enter number to be deleted")
   f = open('members.txt', 'w')
   index = 0
   for index in range(1,total):
      index = index + 1
      if index != entry:
         f.write(contents[index])
```

Comment: You start from `index == 1` in the `range` and increment *before* writing; Python indices are `0`-based, so you skip the first two lines (`0` and `1`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import sys
import os

def erase(file):
   assert os.path.isfile(file)
   with open(file, 'r') as f:
      content = f.read().split("\n")
   #print content                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
   entry = input("Enter number to be deleted:")
   assert entry >= 0 and entry < len(content)
   new_file = content[:entry] + content[entry+1:]
   #print new_file                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
   with open(file,'w') as f:
      f.write("\n".join(new_file))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   erase(sys.argv[1])
```

As already noted you were starting the range from 1 which is incorrect. List slicing which I used in `new_file = content[:entry] + content[entry+1:]` makes the code more readable and it is an approach less prone to similar errors.

Also you seem to open and close the input file at the beginning for no reason. Also you should use `with` if possible when doing operations with files.

Finally I used the `join` and `split` to simplify the code so you don't need a for loop to process the lines of the file.